# Refreshing text box from a bindingsource from an SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, bindingsource

I want to wire a text box to a `BindingSource`. I tried this:

```
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select col1, col2, from table1", conn);
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dt);

            bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;

            textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "col1");
```

When I run it, it says this:
    Cannot bind to the property or column col1 on the DataSource.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: they have discussed this topic in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244640/c-refreshing-textbox-from-bindingsource

Comment: I have seen that post. It does not include anything about SQL which is my main problem here (the code works when I modify it to get the data from an XML string like in some tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
BindingSource _bs;


private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    //  Creamos el objeto BindingSource
    _bs = new BindingSource();
    //  Establecemos la conexi?n para recuperar los datos
    //  de los Clientes.
    // 
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);");
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Clientes";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    //  Rellenamos el objeto DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Clientes");
    //  Le asignamos el origen de datos al objeto BindingSource
    // 
    _bs.DataSource = ds;
    //  Objeto DataSet
    _bs.DataMember = "Clientes";
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bs, "IdCliente");
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bs, "Nombre");
    //  Enlazamos el control BindingNavigator
    // 
    BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = _bs;
}
```